# How do I avoid max connections error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

This happens pretty frequently (once a week for about 30-40 minutes), where all of a sudden my database mentions max connections when I try to connect via heidisql, and any apis calls respond with the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'release' of undefined
```

I am calling .release() after every query in mysql. Is there something I am missing, am I suppose to call .end as well? I am using nodejs with mysql.

Here is the way I wrap every query and the pool code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var mysql_pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: config.mysql.limit,
    host: config.mysql.host,
    user: config.mysql.user,
    password: config.mysql.pw,
    database: config.mysql.db //,
    // debug: true
});
var qSelect = "SELECT id FROM Users";
    var qValues = [];
    var qCall = mysql.format(qSelect, qValues);
    mysql_pool.getConnection(function(err_pool, connection) {
        if (err_pool) {
            connection.release();
            console.log(' Error getting mysql_pool connection: ' + err_pool);
            throw err_pool;
        }
        connection.query(qCall, function(err, userFound, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) {
                console.log("get user : " + err);
            } else {
               //some code here
            }

        });
```

Can someone please advise, appreciate it.

Comment: if the connection  fails you have no connection that you can release

Comment: as per the solution mentioned below, will that avoid this issue? I am getting max user connections though as the error which makes no sense

Comment: the code in err code is definitely wrong because there is no connection to  release, but i think your error comes from the second release, can you check if connection is available ad see if console.log(pool._freeConnections.indexOf(connection)); give you a -1

Comment: It was coming from the first one, so I did remove it from there, but if I do get rid of it, how do I stop the other error where it mentions max connections. I am the only one using the db so it makes no sense to me unless somehow connections are left idle or open... if so, anyway to close those?

Comment: why do you need 200 or more conection, if you are the only one, multi threading?. you have to take a steo back and overthing the hle concept, with all parts. A white board or a even  a Word page is helpful.  connection is quite a problem, because many components can lmit the number of connections first see if you can limit the connections.

Comment: Im using heroku and have a max 10 connection limit, also running multiple workers so they could all be hitting the db?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove first `connection.release()` used in if loop

```
if (err_pool) {
            console.log(' Error getting mysql_pool connection: ' + err_pool);
            throw err_pool;
        }
```

Comment: but wouldnt it not be released if an error is thrown, and then be left open?

Comment: If an error is thrown that means no connection is established so there is no use in first error loop but if connection is established and there is an error related to query then we are using connection.release() in error loop

Comment: Ok so taking that away, what about the max connections... how is that possible or what can I do to free up any idle ones?

Comment: As you have mentioned in comment, it might be due to heroku max connection. Check it on your local mysql this code should work fine.

Comment: I do see max connections,  but I have nothing running so it makes no sense...

Comment: Actually it makes no sense. Check if server is running any background process. Also when you face max connections issue check Database size at the same time as heroku allows only 5MB